# What is the role of kernel's top level Makefile while compiling a new module?

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

For creating a new kernel module we need to use kernel's top level Makefile as:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=`pwd`
```

`-C` specifies the path of the top level Makefile.

My question is what is the need of this Makefile while creating a new module? When my makefile should be sufficient for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While kernel module is compiled using the same compiler (`gcc`) as user-space programs, it is required to pass **many special parameters** to the compiler for create a module. Moreover, some of these parameters depends on the kernel, against which you build the module.

Yes, you may create the Makefile, which passes proper parameters to the compiler and creates a module.

However, it is much simpler to use existing kernel's Makefile which cares about these parameters. In that case, your makefile needs to provide only source files you wish to compile into the module.

---

Also, **building** the kernel module is not just a *compiling* it. Asides from invoking the compiler, some additional actions should be taken for prepare the module.

E.g., one need to prepropcess `Modules.symvers` file for extract information of kernel core functions which are used in the module. Without that step the module created cannot be inserted into the kernel.